# Get ONLY the count of members of 'User' type from an AAD group using Graph API

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Is there a Graph API to get the count of members of a specific type from AAD group? For example, consider the following AAD group:

[image]

This group contains 3 members of type 'User'. Is there a Graph API to get ONLY that count i.e. 3? Or should I get all members from the group and do some filtering to get the members of 'User' type as follows and find out the count:

```
var users = new List<Guid>();
var response = await graphClient
           .Groups[groupId]
           .TransitiveMembers
           .Request()           
           .GetAsync();

users.AddRange(ToUsers(response));

private IEnumerable<Guid> ToUsers(IEnumerable<DirectoryObject> members)
{
            foreach (var directoryObj in fromGraph)
            {
                switch (directoryObj)
                {                    
                    case User user:
                        yield return Guid.Parse(user.Id);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: any update on it?

Answer (score 1):

To get the count of members of a **specific type** from AAD group, you can make use of below query:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<group_id>/members/microsoft.graph.user/$count
```

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I created one **Azure AD group** with members of different types like below:

[image]

I ran the below query via ***Graph Explorer*** and got the count of members of **`User`** type successfully as below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<group_id>/members/microsoft.graph.user/$count
```

Make sure to add **`ConsistencyLevel : Eventual`** request header while running the query.

**Response:**

[image]

You can get the code in any language by selecting **Code snippets** tab like below:

[image]

**Code sample in C#**

```cs
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var int32 = await graphClient.Groups["groupID"].Members.$count
.Request()
.Header("ConsistencyLevel","Eventual")
.GetAsync();
```

Comment: Does this return all users along with the count? All I need is the count.

Comment: Yes, it will return all members `count` with **User** type.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let's see the graph [api example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-3-use-odata-cast-to-get-only-a-count-of-user-membership) which is the same with your requirement. It requires `/members/microsoft.graph.user`, but Graph SDK does not currently support filtering by derived types which is a known issue, see [this issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/MSGraph-SDK-Code-Generator/issues/239). So we need to use code like this:

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "aad_app_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var groupUrl = graphClient.Groups["group_id"].Members.AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("microsoft.graph.user");
var groupRequest = await new GraphServiceGroupsCollectionRequest(groupUrl, graphClient, null).GetAsync();
var userCount = groupRequest.Count;
```

We need to use `AppendSegmentToRequestUrl` to append `microsoft.graph.user` in the request and it worked for me.

[image]

By the way, you may want to append `/$count` as well. so that the code should like below:

```
var requestOptions = new List<HeaderOption>()
{
    new HeaderOption("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
};
var groupUrl = graphClient.Groups["group_id"].Members.AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("microsoft.graph.user/$count");
var groupRequest = await new GraphServiceGroupsCollectionRequest(groupUrl, graphClient, requestOptions).GetAsync();
```

But it will throw exception, because the response is a number but not `Group`. So we can't use it except we use http client to send get request manually, but it's not related to graph SDK then. Anyway I'll share the code here.

```
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(scopes);
var token = clientSecretCredential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext).Result.Token;
httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token );
var groupUrl = graphClient.Groups["group_id"].Members.AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("microsoft.graph.user/$count");
HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(groupUrl);
```

In the last, pls see screenshot below. So the code snippet generated by graph explorer is wrong.

[image]